# open source GPGPU project for protein folding

Tags: open-source, cuda, opencl, gpgpu, modeling

I am looking for an open source GPGPU project for protein folding (CUDA/OpenCL). Would you please giving me some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Gromacs? http://www.gromacs.org/Downloads/Installation_Instructions/GPUs

Comment: MUMer-GPU? http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/mummergpu/index.php?title=MUMmerGPU

Comment: Thanks. I will check them out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folding@home is probably the largest GPU-based protein folding project by far.  So you would probably do well to use whatever they use: [Folding@home open source FAQ](http://folding.stanford.edu/English/FAQ-OpenSource).  That appears to be a custom version of Gromacs and [OpenMM](https://simtk.org/home/openmm).

A full list of software like this is here: [Molecular modeling on GPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_modeling_on_GPUs).  Notable software packages in addition to GROMACS/OpenMM include NAMD (which has been around since 1995), and ACEMD.

These can be classified into molecular dynamics (using empirical potential fields), ab-initio (using quantum mechanics), and hybrid.  None of these are protein-folding-specific, but most of the molecular dynamics packages can handle protein-folding-sized problems.  The ab-initio packages aren't there yet, but getting close.

Comment: @Josh Vo: Does this answer your question?  If yes, please remember to accept the answer.

Comment: Alex, sorry for delays. Thanks a lot for the information. I have accepted it!